# Ratchet js modal position

Tags: javascript, html, css, ratchet-bootstrap

I have the modal sliding out from the right hand side and I have the modal size set to 80% but it slides out to the left hand side of the screen but I want it to be on the right hand side.

How can I do this?

The code for the current modal is;

```
modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 11;
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .25s, opacity 1ms .25s;
     -moz-transition:    -moz-transform .25s, opacity 1ms .25s;
          transition:         transform .25s, opacity 1ms .25s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
.modal.active {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .25s;
     -moz-transition:    -moz-transform .25s;
          transition:         transform .25s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: You want your modal to be fixed on the right of your screen? Use right: 0; However, I'm not sure that I really understand the question, could you JSFiddle this?

Comment: right:0; keeps i ton the right side but it now makes closing the modal very jerky, on closing it jumps to the left then slides away to the right

Comment: Don't put it on the .active class